# Best flavor of Linux for an Acer Revo 3600 as media server?

Tags: hdmi

I would like to try Linux on my Acer Revo 3600 (ION) in the hopes that it will perform better than Windows 7, which is extremely sluggish.

"All" I need it to do is:

1. Run Plex Media Server
2. Run uTorrent
3. Run LogMeIn (or VNC if necessary)
4. Be able to connect to my network over WiFi (with dongle)
5. Be able to mount SMB shares on the network
6. Support HDMI Video & Audio output
7. Support the Revo's hardware accelerated HD playback

I want an "easy" installation but something that is lean and will run smoothly.

Comment: Use the Linux you most familiar with.

Comment: The Revo was never powerful enough for Plex transcoding and streaming HD media to clients. It would work well as a client for HD video if you get HW (ION) accelerated playback working.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "Best" solution, it is really up to the user which solution is "Best".
Regardless of this, you have a few options that suit your needs...

#### Ubuntu server

This would suit your needs after a few `apt-get install` commands. you don't need to be an expert to use terminal commands :P (see tab auto-complete)"

http://www.ubuntu.com/server/

#### OpenELEC Mediacenter

This includes XBMC by default which has all the plugins required to get what you want and more but you might need to run a few terminal commands to get things like plex and LogMeIn.

http://openelec.tv/

#### Any distro

Any distro could be used for this. Just install the appropriate software and set it up for what you need.

Hope you can find what you're looking for.